# Symfony2 handling collections on forms

Tags: forms, symfony

Is there any "easy" way to handle `collection` type on entity creation form?

What I've got:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
// ...
class Book
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $otherTitles;
    // ...
}
```

In the form builder:

```
// ...
->add('bookOtherTitles', 'collection', array(
      'label' => "Other Title(s)",
      'required'=>false,
      'allow_add'=>true
     ))
// ...
```

What I want - in the Perfect World - is that the field would display one text text input (ok, a `vars.prototype` can do that one) and a little "+" sign next to it, allowing me to add more fields, but probably I will have to do it myself in JS. My question is, is my approach the best one here (with `array` entity field and `collection` field in form)?

Bonus question: how to handle multiple inputs - I assume i need to trick the form into giving them names with `[]`?

Maybe I started in a wrong way? I didn't create a separate entity for that field, because I know every "other title" will be just string and will not be assigned to any other Book. Maybe that was a mistake? Should I create an entity with only one field and use `OneToMany` in `Book` entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add by twig extension in prototype `data-prototype="{{...|e}}{{your_twig_return}}"`. Please read this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html Dont forget `{{your_twig_return}}` should return `htmlentities`. After that style it by css and then viola.

Anyway, I think the best way is use JS instead of using twig extension. Its very simple btw.

how to handle multiple inputs? dont worry about that, symfony already handle that. Please read this : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html careful.